# Proving that ${k+x \choose 2k + 1}=-{k-x \choose 2k + 1} $

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, proof-verification

I need to prove the following, someone can help me?

${k+x \choose 2k + 1}=-{k-x \choose 2k + 1} $

I tried the following:

$\frac{(k+x)!}{(2k + 1)!((k+x)-(2k+1))!}  = -1\frac{(k-x)!}{(2k + 1)!((k-x)-(2k+1))!} $

$\frac{(k+x)!}{(2k + 1)!(x-k-1))!}  = -1\frac{(k-x)!}{(2k + 1)!(-x -k -1)!} $

How to continue?

Comment: Binomial coefficients are never negative, so there is an issue with the equality that you are trying to prove. For example $\binom{5}{10}$ is zero, rather than negative. Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by the notation.

Comment: In probability theory and statistics, the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) is a discrete probability distribution of the number of successes in a sequence of independent.

Comment: Dario - that's true, but of course the "number of successes" cannot itself be a negative number. So, if the notation in the post refers to binomial coefficients, it is impossible for one side of the equality to be positive and the other negative unless both sides are zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(2k+1)-(k+x)-1=k-x$, the upper number of $\binom{k-x}{2k+1}$. Thus, you can [negate the upper index](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Negated_Upper_Index_of_Binomial_Coefficient):

$$\binom{k+x}{2k+1}=(-1)^{2k+1}\binom{(2k+1)-(k+x)-1}{2k+1}\;,$$

and I’ll leave you to finish off the last couple of steps.

By the way, the $x$ should suggest that you’re dealing with the generalized binomial coefficient $\binom{y}k$ defined for arbitrary real $y$ and non-negative integers $k$ by

$$\binom{y}k=\frac{y^{\underline k}}{k!}\;,$$

where

$$y^{\underline k}=\underbrace{y(y-1)(y-2)\ldots(y-k+1)}_{k\text{ factors}}$$

is a [falling factorial power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). The definition that you used is applicable only to non-negative integer upper numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Very elegant the solution (y)

Comment: @Dario: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The above property is based in *Euler Reflection Formula* as 'translated to factorials':
>   $\ds{z!\pars{-z - 1}! = -\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi z}}}$:

\begin{align}
{\pars{k + x}! \over \pars{x - k - 1}!} & =
\bracks{-\,{\pi \over \pars{-1 - k - x}!\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{-k - x}}}}
\bracks{-\,{\pars{k - x}!\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{x - k}} \over \pi}}
\\[3mm] & = {\pars{k - x}! \over \pars{-1 - k - x}!}\,\ \underbrace{%
{-\cos\pars{\pi\bracks{k + 1}} \over -\cos\pars{\pi k}}}_{\ds{=\ -1}}
\end{align}

---

Then,
$$
\color{#f00}{{k + x \choose 2k + 1}} = {1 \over \pars{2k + 1}!}\,
\bracks{-\,{\pars{k - x}! \over \pars{-1 - k - x}!}} =
\color{#f00}{-{k - x \choose 2k + 1}}
$$

Comment: Wonderful equation! 
I need to learn more about the Euler's Formula Reflection.
very interesting!!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle f(x):=\binom{k+x}{2k+1}+\binom{k-x}{2k+1}\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  Note that $\deg\big(f(x)\big)<2k+1$, as both $\displaystyle\binom{k+x}{2k+1}$ and $\displaystyle\binom{k-x}{2k+1}$ are polynomials of degree $2k+1$ in $x$ and the coefficients of $x^{2k+1}$ in $f(x)$ is $$\dfrac{1}{(2k+1)!}+\dfrac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=0\,.$$  The equality $f(x)=0$ holds for $x=-k,-k+1,\ldots,k-1,k$ (as $\displaystyle\binom{k+x}{2k+1}=\binom{k-x}{2k+1}=0$ for these values of $x$).  Hence, $f(x)$ is the zero polynomial as it vanishes at $2k+1$ distinct values and its degree is less than $2k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

is it OK ?

${k+x \choose 2k + 1}=-{k-x \choose 2k + 1} $

$\binom{k+x}{2k+1}=(-1)^{2k+1}\binom{(2k+1)-(k+x)-1}{2k+1}\;$

$=(-1)^{2k+1}\binom{2k-(k+x)}{2k+1}$

$=(-1)^{2k+1}\frac{(2k-(k+x)).(2k-(k+x) -1).(2k-(k+x)-2) ... (2k-(k+x)-2k) }{(2k+1)!}$

$=\frac{-1(2k-(k+x)).-1(2k-(k+x) -1).-1(2k-(k+x)-2) ... -1(2k-(k+x)-2k) }{(2k+1)!}$

$=\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}.((k+x)-2k).((k+x) -2k +1).((k+x)-2k +2) ... ((k+x)-2k+2k)$

$=\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}.(\frac{(k+x)!}{((k+x)-2k-1)!})$

$=\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}.(\frac{(k+x)!}{((k+x)-(2k +1))!})$

$=\frac{(k+x)!}{(2k+1)! . ((k+x)-(2k +1))!}$

$=\binom{k+x}{2k+1}$

q.e.d.